# Create dummy variables for interdependent categories in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to set up a linear regression model in order to predict traffic counts based on the day, and the time of day. Since both are categorical variables, I have to create dummy variables. The `get_dummies` function makes this very easy, when doing this for both variables individually. However, in the case of predicting traffic volumes, the interdependence between the day and the time of day are important. Therefore, I'll need dummies for all days * all time intervals.

I made a small example, avoiding to trouble you with big datasets:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
                    'Time': [11,15,9,15,17,10,20],
                    'Count': [100,150,150,150,180,60,50]})

df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.Day)

print(df_dummies)
```

Results in a nice dataframe with dummies:

```
   Fri  Mon  Sat  Sun  Thu  Tue  Wed
0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
2    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
3    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
4    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
5    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
6    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
```

So what I'm after is something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
                    'Time': [11,15,9,15,17,10,20],
                    'Count': [100,150,150,150,180,60,50]})

df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.Day * df.Time)

print(df_dummies)
```

With a result like this:

```
   Fri_9  Fri_15  Mon_9 Mon_15 Sat_9 Sat_15 Sun_9 ...
0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0 ...
1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0 ...
2    0    0    0    0    0    0    1 ...
3    0    0    0    0    1    0    0 ...
4    1    0    0    0    0    0    0 ... 
5    0    0    1    0    0    0    0 ...
6    0    0    0    1    0    0    0 ...
7    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 ...
[...]
```

Is there any way in which this can be done elegantly?

Comment: What is size of data? Performance is important?

Comment: I have approximately 16.000 rows. The dummy variables are for every 10 minutes, for each day of the week (so 144*7 = 1008 dummies). So I guess performance is quite important in order to do some calculations.

Comment: OK, so try my answer too? I guess it should be faster. (but it depends of your data mainly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to set up a linear regression model in order to predict

Technically, you can make a dummy of the tuples:

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(df[['Day', 'Time']].apply(tuple, axis=1))

(Fri, 17)   (Mon, 11)   (Sat, 10)   (Sun, 20)   (Thu, 15)   (Tue, 15)   (Wed, 9)
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
3   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
4   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
...
```

however, I think this approach is not the best at the ML level. This will probably fragment the data very much, making things hard for your regressor. You might consider using a gradient-boosted decision tree, if you're after the interactions.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be a very simple way to do this. This was exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: Can you explain why I might prefer tuples instead of the strings, as posted in the solution of jezrael?

Comment: @Jeroen There is no real reason - both tuples and underscores are valid approaches. The advantage of underscores is that they're valid python identifiers, and the advantage of tuples is that you don't need to split to get the day and hour. You can use (and accept) either answer. My main point is about your use of linear models with such fragmentation.

Answer (score 2):

I belive need join columns together with cast to `string`s:

```
df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.Day + '_' + df.Time.astype(str))

#df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.Day.str.cat(df.Time.astype(str), sep='_'))

print(df_dummies)
   Fri_17  Mon_11  Sat_10  Sun_20  Thu_15  Tue_15  Wed_9
0       0       1       0       0       0       0      0
1       0       0       0       0       0       1      0
2       0       0       0       0       0       0      1
3       0       0       0       0       1       0      0
4       1       0       0       0       0       0      0
5       0       0       1       0       0       0      0
6       0       0       0       1       0       0      0
```

Comment: Method works as well, and is slightly faster than the method of Ami Tavory.

Comment: @Jeroen - If no problem, what is difference? I am curious

Comment: The difference is in the column names. At this moment I'm not sure whether to prefer tuples (@Ami) or concatenated strings.

Comment: @Jeroen - Sure, maybe Ami is now offline, but I think get answer for comment. But in pandas I think better are strings, because better working with it - but still depends of what need.

Comment: I like the use of underscores, as it creates valid identifiers. BTW, if you're planning to input this into a regressor, I think the timing of this stage should be negligible.